# Module.exports with constructor and other objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
let Token = mongoose.model("Token", InToken)

let add = () => {
    return 1 + 1
}

module.exports = {
    Token,
    add
}
```

Whenever I do this, I receive this error: `TypeError: Token is not a constructor`.

How can I export the model along with other objects?

Comment: how are you importing Token?

Comment: Show us how you use this module. The error you are getting doesn't come from the code you posted, it comes from the code that does import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import your module with

```
const Something = require('./Something'); // contains the file in your question
```

you will be able to use `new` with:

```
const token = new Something.Token()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import Token like this:

`const { Token } = require("path to token model");`